# Searching for literal strings like '***' using less

Tags: regular-expression, less

In trying to search for the literal string `***`, less puts up a couple roadblocks. The asterisk has a special meaning when used as the first character of the search pattern (ignore EOF). No problem, just escape it with a backslash. Now, since I'm searching for a literal string, I don't want the asterisks treated as regex special characters. Again, no problem: starting a search with ^R turns off regex searching.

See the problem yet? With regex off, there's no way to escape the initial asterisk! So my only choice seems to be: keep regex enabled, and either individually escape each asterisk (i.e. I have to type `/\*\*\*`), or use something like `/\*{3}`, neither of which is particularly pleasant to type.  Other than relying on custom key bindings in `~/.lesskey`, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I'm struggling to imagine what would be easier than `/\*\*\*`.  Did you have something in mind?

Comment: @jesse_b, OP mentioned `^R` which normally allows you not to have to worry about what character may be a regexp operator, but here doesn't work.

Comment: You can do `/<Ctrl-R> ***<Home><Delete><Enter>` (ie add a leading space and remove it after). Not great either.

Comment: @jesse_b, I had hoped that something like ```/\***``` or ```/^R***``` would work, but no.

Comment: @dhm, `/\***` matches 0 or more `*`s (so including the empty string, so everywhere) without ^R and `\***` with ^R